# CSV Helper first row been skipped

Tags: asp.net, csvhelper

I am using CSV Helper to read a CSV file but the first row is been skipped, I saw that it can be a configuration but I can't see how to force the reading of the first row.

Any ideas?

```cs
try
{
    using var csv = new CsvReader(file);
    var records = csv.GetRecords<TMap>().ToList();
    return _mapper.Map<List<T>>(records.ToList());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception($"Error parsing the Csv File. Error: {e.Message}");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the configuration first.

Try this

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
};
try
{

    using var csv = new CsvReader(file, config);

    var records = csv.GetRecords<TMap>().ToList();
    return _mapper.Map<List<T>>(records.ToList());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception($"Error parsing the Csv File. Error: {e.Message}");
}
```

Comment: I will try and come back you. Thanks for the fast reply.